# How to convert selected option value to HTML5 code

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I'm using MVC4 and HTML5 to develop my project. I declared select tag and options, each option has its own value. When I select an option, I can see its value in a alert.

```
<select name="select" onchange="drawOption(this)">
    <option value="">--- Cizgi Tipi Seçiniz ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Basit Semboller ---</option>
    <option value="new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol();">Default</option>
    <option value="new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE, 10, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,new dojo.Color([210, 105, 30, 0.5]), 8), new dojo.Color([210, 105, 30, 0.9]))" >Square</option>
</select>
```

In the JavaScript, I want to use this value to create object and assign in to a var variable. Related function (It is not drawOption function, addGraphic function is triggered after some functions) :

```
function addGraphic(pt) {
    var idx = element.selectedIndex;
    alert(element.options[idx].value);
    var symbol = element.options[idx].value;
    // var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE, 10, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([210, 105, 30, 0.5]), 8),
    //new dojo.Color([210, 105, 30, 0.9]));
    graphic = new esri.Graphic(pt, symbol);
    map.graphics.add(graphic);
}
```

In the alert, I can see value. However, it does not assign to symbol variable. 
I think, it assigns it as string, so I can not create new object.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where `element` is defined, so it is hard to tell. I think you are assigning a string to `symbol`, namely `"new esri.symbo...."`.

Maybe using `eval (...)` will help? (Beware of security issues!)

Regards, nobi